# Create a shuffled Array that I can use in all functions thereafter

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, function, ibaction

Hi I'm trying to shuffle an array which I can then use in all my IBAction functions thereafter in the order that I shuffled them. Example of code which is the same idea as what I have...

```
Class ViewContoller: UIViewContoller
Let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()   }
```

I've tried to write a function here to create an array which has been shuffled so I can use that shuffled array ...

```
func shuffledArray() -> Array<Int> { 
let numbersArray = numbers.shuffled() 
return numbersArray }
let myListOfShuffledNumbers = shuffledArray()
```

Now this works in playground.. but when I try this my viewcontroller.swift I get error 'cannot use instance member 'shuffledArray' within property initializer; property initializers run before self is available.

So I know if I'm in a IBAction func I can run the function `let shuffledNumbers = shuffledArray()`and get an Array of shuffled numbers to use but my problem is I need to use that same shuffle order in another IBAction function. So how can I make a universal array of shuffled numbers to use anywhere on my view controller.

I've tried `lazy var myListOfShuffledNumbers = shuffledArray()`

This gets rid of my error but it doesn't help me because I get a 2 different list order when I use 'myListOfShuffledNumbers' in 2 different IBAction functions

What can I do ?? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a property that you can access from anywhere in your `ViewContoller`, like this:

```
class ViewContoller: UIViewContoller {

    let unshuffledNumbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
    var myListOfShuffledNumbers = [Int]() /// here! it's still empty at first

    @IBAction func firstButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        myListOfShuffledNumbers = unshuffledNumbers.shuffled()
    }

    @IBAction func secondButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        /// do something with myListOfShuffledNumbers here...
    }
}
```

At first, `myListOfShuffledNumbers` is still an empty array of `Int`s. But inside your first `IBAction`, you can assign that to `unshuffledNumbers.shuffled()`. Then, you can access it from inside your second `IBAction`.

Also it might be easier to just write `[Int]` instead of `Array<Int>` -- they are the same thing.

```
func shuffledArray() -> [Int] { 
    let numbersArray = numbers.shuffled() 
    return numbersArray
}
```

Comment: "You can define a global var". myListOfShuffledNumbers is not a global var. It is an instance property of ViewController

Comment: @LeoDabus I will fix

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.. I've been stuck on this all night .. I just popped the empty var ( as recommended) above the initial class view controller business and its seems to be global .. thank you again 

Comment: @BC147 hmm, global vars are actually discouraged, I think. My original answer was misleading. If you only need to access the var from inside `ViewController`, then keep it inside there.

Comment: @aheze when I tried your method I found that in second button pushed myListOfShuffledNumbers Array came up empty. I think I know why.. I have 2 scenes (viewcontrollers) in storyboard but only 1 viewcontroller.swift. My second button is in scene 2. I was trying to control both though my 1 viewcontroller.swift file. Which is why it returned empty and when I placed it above viewcontroller class it worked. Do you think I should open a new file viewcontroller2.swift and try and pass myListOfShuffledNumbers over to it ? Using a prepare for segue? Would that be cleaner option or something else?thanks

Comment: Oh... ok. So, you *can* have multiple classes in one `.swift` file. I'm assuming you have one `ViewController` class and another `ViewController2` class? And each scene in the storyboard is set to their corresponding class? You should then have a `myListOfShuffledNumbers` in both view controllers (one in each). Then, when presenting your second view controller, you can do something like:

Comment: `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil); if let viewController2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2ID") as? ViewController2 { self.present(viewController, animated: true); viewController2.myListOfShuffledNumbers = self.myListOfShuffledNumbers }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an array that is shuffled then just convert it to a set. Sets will not keep the original order of the array.

Comment: But doesn't this also mean that the `set` will be different every time you access it? Op said *my problem is I need to use that same shuffle order in another IBAction function.*

Comment: Yes that is true. Then one thing he could do is make the array `numbers` private and then make a computed property `shuffled numbers` that would be able to do it.